# Magento2 How to Change Status New order from pending to Complete

Tags: magento2.3.7

I tried a lot to change the status New order from pending to complete
iclick open the box for the status i don't show any other statues only Pending

[image]

Comment: An order will move to status Complete only when invoice and shipment are created. You can't directly change it from Pending to Complete.

Comment: @LokeshNaik thank you for replay yes after i clicked on invoiced this created the order Complete

Answer (score 0):

If Payment is recieved then you just need to create the invoice by using the option above and then to process the order use the Ship option after creating the invoice then the order status will change to Complete